# How to turn on automatic brightness in React Native Android?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, brightness

I want to enable automatic brightness in my react native android app.

for example, user is able to enable automatic brightness when clicked to a button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this package `expo-brightness` https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/brightness/#brightnesssetsystembrightnessmodeasyncbrightnessmode

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Brightness from 'expo-brightness';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Brightness.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        // ANDROID ONLY
        Brightness.setSystemBrightnessModeAsync(BrightnessMode.AUTOMATIC)
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Brightness Module Example</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If you use it outside expo project follow this instructions: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-47/packages/expo-brightness